# How to add a constraint to an EF Code First table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

First, I'm not sure if I'm reinventing the wheel with regards to foreign keys here, but lets say I have a Patient table

```
PatientId
Name
Gender
Age
HospitalId
```

I want to make sure that when an object is inserted into the Patient table, that it won't insert a record with a HospitalId that doesn't exist in the Hospital table. Is there an efficient way of doing this? Or as I said above am I reinventing a wheel here?

Comment: thats handled in database. when a foreign key has been made. even if you try to insert. an exception would be thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Gender {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public int HospitalId {get;set;}

    //add this line of code
    public virtual Hospital Hospital {get;set;}
}
```

Also you can change `Hospital` class this way:

```
public class Hospital 
{
    //your code....
    //new property
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients {get;set;}    
}
```

Comment: Can you create a relationship without creating a foreign key? Running Add-Migration and Update-Database with those changes does create a foreign key.

Comment: No, FK is exactly, what you need. Another solution is to create trigger, but it will be more complicated.